# Unable to mount exFAT dev/sdb2

Tags: command-line, data-recovery, exfat

I am unable to mount dev/sdb2 exfat filesystem. help me guys.

[image: Unable to mount exfat]

Comment: Are you sure it's exfat? What happens if you try `sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt`?

Comment: error:exFAT file system is not found

Comment: You get that error message when you're not specifying any file system?

Comment: when I type this command sudo mount -t exfat /dev/sdb2 /mnt/ I am getting error: exfat file system is not found

Comment: I ask you what happens if you type `sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt`. What error message do you get?

Comment: I don't see the picture you've posted for some reason. It is probably a window of a terminal with some text output, which should have been copy/pasted. Anyway, check if you have `exfat-utils` installed: `dpkg -l | grep exfat-utils`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to mount exfat formatted partitions, you need exfat support in your system. exfat support is not by default enabled on Ubuntu. To install support for exfat, install `exfat-fuse`.

```
sudo apt install exfat-fuse
```

After that, you can mount the partition either by clicking on it in the file manager or, using the terminal for example as:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdx /mnt
```

Note that there is no need to specify the file system: if the partition is healthy, the `mount` command should recognize the type automatically.

If you are unsure about the file system of a certain partition, you can run

```
lsblk -f
```

Comment: According to the output in the screenshot, he has ExFAT Fuse installed, [version 1.2.3](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/exfat-fuse), which points to 16.04...

Comment: I know. He asked about exfat mounting. I just provided a general anwer about mounting exfat. Added some info on the actual mounting.